# Tkinter - Difference between Entry and str(same val)?

Tags: python, tkinter

```
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("Nado")

lab_pro_val4 = Label(root)
lab_pro_val4 = Label(root, text='DD', width=30, height=1)
lab_pro_val4.pack()

ent_pro_val4 = Entry(root)
ent_pro_val4.pack()

def btncmd4_add():
    tru = ent_pro_val4.get() == 'TEST123'
    print(tru)

btn4_ppid = Button(root, text='Check', command=btncmd4_add(), bg='White')
btn4_ppid.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

I typed `TEST123` but I got `False` not `True` — why not? 
I think it's same. plz let me know... Which thing makes it wrong?

Comment: Problem is `command=btncmd4_add()`. Don't call the function, just pass the function itself, i.e. `command=btncmd4_add`. Otherwise the function is executed once, before you typed anything, and the actual `command` is `None`.

Comment: `command=` and `root.bind()` and `root.after()` needs function's name without `()` - this commonly is called `callback` - and later `tkinter` will use `()` to execute it (ie. when you press button or use assigned key). The same can be in other languages.